# Экранирование разделителя для split

Tags: python

Всем привет!
использую функцию split(';') для разделения строки на список.
Но пришла строка в которой содержится ; как часть элемента, как экранировать ';' в строке, чтобы split(';') не использовал этот символ как разделитель?

Comment: Любым символом, только потом придётся регулярку писать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно именно экранировать точку с запятой, то можно экранировать её, например, обратным слэшом `\`. В этом случае нужно использовать split из модуля регулярных выражений re.

```
import re
test = 'ok;block;ugolok\;qwe'
re.split(r'(?<![\\]);', test)
```

> ['ok', 'block', 'ugolok\;qwe']

Конструкция `(?<![\\])` называется отрицательный просмотр назад.

Comment: а что если слэш сам заэкранирован: `r'not escaped\\;'`?

Comment: @jfs Тогда разделение все равно в этом месте не будет происходить. Если нужно другое поведение, то лучше использовать другой разделитель.

Comment: смысл комментария в том что обычно если \ имеет специальное значение, то \\ означает буквальный слэш. Можно cvs модуль использовать, чтобы не изобретать велосипед с квадратными колёсами

Comment: Использую конструкцию r'(?<!["]);'
как можно удалить символ экранирования?

Comment: Если результат разбиения хранится в переменной res, то можно заменить все экранированные ';' командой `res = [part.replace('\;',';') for part in res]`

Answer (score 3):

Если ваш формат требует экранирования разделителя, то количество различных (неочевидных) крайних случаев резко возрастает. Чтобы не изобретать парсер для своего формата (и свои баги), [можно csv модулем воспользоваться](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```
>>> import csv
>>> list(csv.reader([r'a;b\;b;c\\;d;e\\\;e'], delimiter=';',
         escapechar='\\', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE))
[['a', 'b;b', 'c\\', 'd', 'e\\;e']]
```

Можно экранировать разделитель с помощью выбранного символа, причём поддерживается и экранирование самого `escapechar`.

Или можно использовать кавычки для экранирования полей:

```
>>> list(csv.reader([r'a;"b;b";c\;d;"e\;e"'], delimiter=';'))
[['a', 'b;b', 'c\\', 'd', 'e\\;e']]
```

Результат тот же.